# Express rest api and mongoDB lowercase query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've created simple Express.js Rest API with MongoDB. I am using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-query-params  and everything works very well except for one thing. I have a URL  like this:

```
localhost/properties/?town=LONDON
```

this returns all properties from London, the problem is with this is the next thing, I need to put capitalize value (LONDON), I am trying to achieve that this value can be lowercase (london), so final URL will be like this:

```
localhost/properties/?town=london
```

My route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Property = require('../models/Property');
const aqp = require ('api-query-params');


router.get('/all', (req, res, next) => {


    const { filter, skip, limit, sort, projection, population, casters } = aqp(req.query, {
        casters: {
          lowercase: val => req.query.toLowerCase(),

        },
      });


    Property.find(filter)
      .skip(skip)
      .limit(limit)
      .sort(sort)
      .select(projection)
      .populate(population)
      .exec((err, properties) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }

        res.send(properties);
      });
  });

module.exports = router;
```

And app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
require('dotenv/config');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const propertyRoute = require('./routes/property');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/properties', propertyRoute);

//routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('value');
});

mongoose.connect('linkdatabse', {
    newUrlParser: true,
})
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I've updated my route according to documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-query-params#add-custom-casting-functions
but still, this doesn't work

Can anybody try to help me with this, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you not getting results with lowercase letters?

Comment: @planet_hunter Yes I need to wright capitalize in order to get results

Comment: Can you please `console.log(filter)` + provide sample data? With `localhost/properties/?town=LONDON` it retuns, but with `localhost/properties/?town=london` it doesn't

Comment: What I can see from your code is - you are converting the filter to lowercase in `aqp` object by iterating over `filterQuery` but passing `filter` object which is coming from object de-structuring. Thus `Property.find(filter)` part in mongo query is always getting uppercase letters. try sending `Property.find(aqp.filter)` instead and check if it works

Comment: @planet_hunter I've updated my route according to documentation, see above:

Comment: @Valijon I've updated my route according to documentation, see above

Comment: Alright what do you see in `console.log(filter)` before firing mongo query?

Comment: @planet_hunter, this is the output from the console: { town: 'london', category: 'rent' }